# Create a Gallery and update Post Parent of Attachment Images

Tags: post-meta, attachments, gallery

I need to create a gallery for a custom-post and update the `post_patent` of every image with the new gallery ID

```
function create_tfuse_gallery_group($post_id) {

    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'vehicle' ) {
        $post_data = array(
            'post_type'     => 'tfuse_gallery_group',
            'post_status'   => 'draft',
            'comment_status'=> 'closed',
            'ping_status'   => 'closed',
            'post_title'    => 'Autotrader Slider Images '.$post_id,
            'post_name'     => 'tf_gallery_autotrader_slider_images_'.$post_id,
        );
        $gallery_post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

        if (is_wp_error($gallery_post_id) || !$gallery_post_id)
            return 0;

        $images = get_attached_media('image', $post_id);

        foreach($images as $image) {
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, array('post_parent' => $gallery_post_id ));
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot see the gallery and the images attached in the post created. Something is probably wrong.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want `wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $image->ID, 'post_parent' => $gallery_post_id ) );` - are you sure you want to do that though? The original parent (`$post_id`) will be lost.

Comment: I searched it a bit more and i figured out that i need to change the post_parent ID of the post-attachment with the ID of the post with post_type `tfuse_gallery_group`, so the gallery be attached to the vehicle post.